# batch file programming multiple variables into one variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

is it possible to do something like this?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set 1=one
set 3=three
set onetwothree=output
echo !%1%two%3%!
pause
```

where the variable %1% will become one and the variable %3% will become three inside of the last variable and then %onetwothree% will echo whatever is set for the output of onetwothree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the idea is correct, this does not work because 1 can not be used as variable name. This is due `%1%` is interpreted as the value of first parameter `%1` followed by a percent sign. Just change the name of these variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set A1=one
set A3=three
set onetwothree=output
echo !%A1%two%A3%!
pause
```